# Установка фреймворка на go

Tags: golang, beego, git

Добрый день.

Хочу установить фреймворк [beego](http://beego.me/). ОС - Windows.

Пытаюсь выполнить первую строку, как написано - `go get github.com/astaxie/beego`.

Сначала пишет, что GoPath пустой. Я его прописываю set GoPath и ставлю папку, где установлен go.

Не хочет качать с гита.

В чём может быть причина? Делаю всё тупо по инструкциям и по видео. Единственное отличие - в примерах линукс или мак, а у меня винда. Не пойму, в чём дело.

---

Ещё вопрос, пишу

```
$ go build main.go
main1.go:4:2: cannot find package "code.google.com/p/go.net/websocket" in any of:
        C:\Go\src\code.google.com\p\go.net\websocket (from $GOROOT)
        ($GOPATH not set)
```

Почему не определены эти свойства? Я написал `export GOPATH=c:/go`, потом проверил go env - св-во GOPATH не пустое.

[image]

Спасибо.

Comment: > Учиться хакерству на машинах, работающих под DOS, Windows или MacOS - это все равно что учиться танцевать, будучи полностью загипсованным.
> -- Eric S. Raymond

Comment: А вообще какая-нибудь другая программа на golang у Вас запускается?

Comment: Подавляющее большинство у кого ты спрашиваешь совета пользуются Линуксом.

Comment: Давайте не будем распылять облако никсового пафоса

Comment: да. Если hello world -всё работает. Пытаюсь что-то по сложнее - начинает ругаться

Comment: Почему может не качать с гита?

Comment: git стоит?

Comment: да - если делаю в консоли от гита http://git-scm.com/ - то не ругается. В обычную консоль он, походу, команды не вписывает там не работает

Comment: Заработало. Как по инструкции. Я не из гитовской консоли писал - вот он и ругался. Спасибо.

Comment: @Роман Ракзин, скорее всего надо просто добавить папку с git в $PATH.

Comment: Вот жесть...

Заскринел :)

Comment: @deterok, спасибо, что сообщили нам

Comment: а устанавливал ли ты GOPATH в переменные среды в панели управления? https://habr.com/post/133281/ в пункте workspace расписано как это делать! К сожалению консоль у винды не очень. Поэтому лучше сделелать это ручками.

Answer (score 2):

Возможно, причина кроется в том, что go переехал с code.google.com и импорт

```
"code.google.com/p/go.net/websocket"
```

стоит изменить на:

```
"golang.org/x/net/websocket"
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте установить значение GOROOT равным "C:\go\" и GOPATH равным "C:\gopath\".
Из документации (http://golang.org/doc/code.html#GOPATH):

> To get started, create a workspace directory and set GOPATH accordingly. Your workspace can be located wherever you like, but we'll use $HOME/go in this document. Note that this must not be the same path as your Go installation.

Это означает, что значение переменной GOPATH не должно совпадать с GOROOT (т.е. директорией, в которой установлен Go)

Answer (score 1):

Возможно вас не установлен на компе git и перед компиляцией не выполнена команда go get code.google.com/p/go.net/websocket